# How to construct a matrix based on the entries of two other matrices?

Tags: matlab

Given a matrix **A** and **B** of same size, i would like to construct the **C** matrix of same size, such that it satisfies the below constraint.

1. if a_ij = 0 then c_ij = min(0,b_ij)
2. if a_ij = 1 then c_ij = max(0,b_ij)
3. if (a_ij <> 0 and a_ij <> 1) then c_ij = b_ij.

where a_ij is the **i-th** and **j-th** entry of **A** matrix.
The entries in the **A** matrix are between 0 and 1.

How optimally we can implement this in matlab. The one i implemented has lot of variables and confusing for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
C = B;
C(A == 0) = min(C(A == 0), 0);
C(A == 1) = max(C(A == 1), 0);
```